# My model summary of VGG is empty? Yet it trains well

Tags: python, keras, deep-learning, transfer

my VGG pre-trained model shows a weird output shape of none.However it trains really well with wonderful results. Is this wrong? Or is it something that I can use.
What does None mean in the model input?

```
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
input_3 (InputLayer)         (None, None, None, 3)     0         
_________________________________________________________________
block1_conv1 (Conv2D)        (None, None, None, 64)    1792      
_________________________________________________________________
block1_conv2 (Conv2D)        (None, None, None, 64)    36928     
_________________________________________________________________
block1_pool (MaxPooling2D)   (None, None, None, 64)    0         
_________________________________________________________________
block2_conv1 (Conv2D)        (None, None, None, 128)   73856     
_________________________________________________________________
block2_conv2 (Conv2D)        (None, None, None, 128)   147584    
_________________________________________________________________
block2_pool (MaxPooling2D)   (None, None, None, 128)   0         
_________________________________________________________________
block3_conv1 (Conv2D)        (None, None, None, 256)   295168    
_________________________________________________________________
block3_conv2 (Conv2D)        (None, None, None, 256)   590080    
_________________________________________________________________
block3_conv3 (Conv2D)        (None, None, None, 256)   590080    
_________________________________________________________________
block3_pool (MaxPooling2D)   (None, None, None, 256)   0         
_________________________________________________________________
block4_conv1 (Conv2D)        (None, None, None, 512)   1180160   
_________________________________________________________________
block4_conv2 (Conv2D)        (None, None, None, 512)   2359808   
_________________________________________________________________
block4_conv3 (Conv2D)        (None, None, None, 512)   2359808   
_________________________________________________________________
block4_pool (MaxPooling2D)   (None, None, None, 512)   0         
_________________________________________________________________
block5_conv1 (Conv2D)        (None, None, None, 512)   2359808   
_________________________________________________________________
block5_conv2 (Conv2D)        (None, None, None, 512)   2359808   
_________________________________________________________________
block5_conv3 (Conv2D)        (None, None, None, 512)   2359808   
_________________________________________________________________
block5_pool (MaxPooling2D)   (None, None, None, 512)   0         
_________________________________________________________________
global_average_pooling2d_12  (None, 512)               0         
_________________________________________________________________
dense_23 (Dense)             (None, 512)               262656    
_________________________________________________________________
dropout_11 (Dropout)         (None, 512)               0         
_________________________________________________________________
dense_24 (Dense)             (None, 4)                 2052
```

Answer (score 2):

`None` shape means it is adaptable to the input.

By doing so, you can run the network on images of different sizes.

And the output will also depend on the input size. You will have a larger-shape output for larger images. Of course, normally we will have a dense layer at the end to pool all the inputs together to feed the loss function.